# Dependency Inversion in swift

Tags: ios, swift, dependency-inversion

Hi I have a question for developer in here, I was reading an iOS programming book from big nerd ranch. I was interested how to structure and technique to create an app. and I was trying to implement it, and it was a dependency inversion and the code is like this

this is the code in app delegate from the book

```
let rootViewController = window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
    let photosViewController = rootViewController.topViewController as! PhotoViewController
    photosViewController.store = PhotoStore()
```

and this is the photoViewController class

```
class PhotoInfoViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

var photo: Photo! {
    didSet {
        navigationItem.title = photo.title
    }
}

var store: PhotoStore!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    store.fetchImage(for: photo) { (result) in
        switch result {
        case let .success(image):
            self.imageView.image = image
        case let .failure(error):
            print("Error fetching image for photo: \(error)")
        }
     }
  }
}
```

and this is the photo store class that use for dependency inversion code

```
enum ImageResult {
    case success(UIImage)
    case failure(Error)
}

enum PhotoError: Error {
    case imageCreationError
}

enum PhotoResult {
    case success([Photo])
    case failure(Error)
}

class PhotoStore {
    private let session: URLSession = {
        return URLSession(configuration: .default)
    }()

    let imageStore = ImageStore()

    func fetchInterestingPhoto(completion: @escaping (PhotoResult) -> Void) {
        let url = FlickerAPI.interestingPhotoURL
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            let result = self.processPhotosRequest(data: data, error: error)

            OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
                completion(result)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }

    private func processPhotosRequest(data: Data?, error: Error?) -> PhotoResult {
        guard let jsonData = data else { return .failure(error!) }
        return FlickerAPI.photos(fromJSON: jsonData)
    }

    func fetchImage(for photo: Photo, completion: @escaping (ImageResult) -> Void) {
        let photoKey = photo.photoID
        if let image = imageStore.image(forKey: photoKey) {
            OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
                completion(.success(image))
            }
            return
        }

        let photoURL = photo.remoteURL
        let request = URLRequest(url: photoURL)

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            let result = self.processImageRequest(data: data, error: error)

            if case let .success(image) = result {
                self.imageStore.setImage(image, forKey: photoKey)
            }

            OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
                completion(result)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }

    private func processImageRequest(data: Data?, error: Error?) -> ImageResult {
        guard
            let imageData = data,
            let image = UIImage(data: imageData)
            else {
                // Couldn't create an image
                if data == nil {
                    return .failure(error!)
                } else {
                    return .failure(PhotoError.imageCreationError)
                }
        }
        return .success(image)
    }
}
```

What I'm asking is, if I have a tab bar controller and have lets say 2 view controller one of them is fetching a news data, and other controller fetching a weather data. how I can implemented this dependency inversion since the root view controller in app delegate will be tab bar controller that's why I confuse to implement it? since the book only use a single view controller.

Comment: What do you understand by Dependency Inversion? Because I don't see any in the code.

Comment: @barbarity what I see is the photo store in app delegate is needed to store a PhotoStore() from root view controller and it can use later by making a type in photoViewController. what I don't understand is how can I implemented it if I have my tab bar controller as root controller in app delegate

Comment: You can subclass tab bar controllers, so that could work?

Comment: @KaneCheshire so the other controller need to be a super class? I still don't get it sorry haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bear in mind this is a hack and in my opinion, it shouldn't be done like this as the dependencies should be declared in the `init`. But because you're probably creating the TabBar from the Storyboard. You only have this option which is getting the TabBar from the window. and the `TabBarController` has an array of the viewControllers that form the TabBar. You simply need to iterate over and try to cast them as a `PhotoViewController`. If it is, then you set the store:

```
let rootViewController = window!.rootViewController as! UITabBarController

for viewController in rootViewController.viewControllers {
    switch viewController {
    case let photoViewController as PhotoViewController:
        photoViewController.store = PhotoStore()
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: ohh I get it. so if the user tab one of view controller, the root view controller change depend user tab. is this also work if I use tabbarcontroller programmatically not using storyboard?

Comment: No, the `rootViewController` doesn't change. The `rootViewController` is a `UITabBarController`. But the `UITabBarController` has an array of `viewControllers` which are defined either in the Storyboard or programmatically. But if you do it programmatically you don't need this as at some point you would set the list of ViewControllers in that TabBar and there you can also set the dependencies.

Comment: You're welcome. Please also upvote so people with the same problem can see the answer easily.